# Not enough storage space to install required resources - AssetModuleException

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm seeing a very strange problem on my Android phone- I have a game published in Google Play that works fine on all of my devices.
Recently, on the same device that used to work just fine, when I download the game from Google Play I get this popup message saying "Error - Not enough storage space to install required resources".
**I haven't updated the game on Google Play at all, it just started happening one day.**

Important to note: the game worked fine on the same phone just a few days ago.
My phone's space is fine, I have 40gb free, and I also tried another Unity game of mine and it loads fine.
Phone model: Galaxy S22.
Logs during launch:

```
2022-09-27 06:36:10.226 25347-27302 E/Finsky: [303] gid.a(75): Request execution failed with error code: -2
com.google.android.finsky.assetmoduleserviceutils.AssetModuleException: Request to PGS failed because all packs are unavailable.
at fkv.Yb(PG:69)
at foy.l(PG:7)
at eqr.run(PG:5)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
2022-09-27 06:36:10.227 27203-27216 E/PlayCore: UID: [10515] PID: [27203] AssetPackServiceImpl : onError(-2)
```

I tried:
cleaning Google Play cache
reboot phone
uninstall/reinstall multiple times from different accounts.

[image]

Comment: Check this might help you. https://forum.unity.com/threads/not-enough-storage-space-to-install-required-resources.1063934/

Comment: thanks, but that looks like a different root cause. I didn't find my answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update- with latest Samsung OS update, this no longer repros for me. I'm on an update from Feb 2023.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with another game. The following steps helped to solve my problem.

1. Install a file explorer app on your phone.
2. Navigate in the main memory of your phone to the folder 'Android/data' search the folder of your game.
3. Try to delete the folder.
4. If deleting does not work, rename the folder to something else and restart your game.

In my case, there were cached files from Unity still in the folder, which were apparently corrupted and could not be deleted by reinstalling the game.

Comment: Renaming helps only once, but since this is a 100% repro, it doesn't help the next time. I think this is a world-wide problem on S22 phones at this point. you can read more in a different post I put in Unity forums- https://forum.unity.com/threads/samsung-s22-broken-with-unity-not-enough-storage-space-to-install-required-resources-100-repro.1349477/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error on my work phone. I had installed Pokemon Go using my work email, and it would give me this message. I then uninstalled it, and re-installed using my personal account and it worked. Not sure how common this is.